# OpenNI: Recorder create function and .oni file creation

Tags: java, openni

This might be a silly question but I am new to OpenNI. Using the OpenNI-Linux-x86-2.2 package.

When I use `Recorder.create(String filename)`, does it create the file or use a pre-existing file? I am asking because I can't find anything which creates .oni files other then making a blank file with .oni suffix (which feels risky).

If it uses a pre-existing .oni file, how do I create one?
The API seems unclear.

Also, is filename just the name without the .oni suffix? (as in, always same directory and not relative/absolute filepath or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with it a little I reached the following:

1. filename is the file path just like when creating java.nio.File objects using the File(String pathname) constructor
2. If no such file exists, it creates one.
3. It works even if a pre-existing file is already there, did not get around to testing if it overwrites it or if it writes at beginning/end